# Image mask not working when I invert it using bitwise_not (OpenCV-Python)

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, python

I am trying to use bitwise operations. In the code below I use 2 images (img1, img2). I create two masks using img2 (gray_inv and gray_test).

```
img1 = cv2.imread('Computer-Vision-with-Python/DATA/dog_backpack.jpg')
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img1 = img1[0:600,0:600]

img2 = cv2.imread('Computer-Vision-with-Python/DATA/watermark_no_copy.png')
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img2 = cv2.resize(img2,(600,600))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
gray_test = cv2.bitwise_not(gray_inv)
```

[image: Output1]

I use a bitwise_or function merge with img1. The first mask works fine. However the second one does not. Am I missing out on something ? Ideally since the they are inverse gray_inv should have showed the background with the text in black.

```
plt.imshow(cv2.bitwise_or(img1,img1, mask=gray_inv))
```

[image: Output2]

```
plt.imshow(cv2.bitwise_or(img1,img1, mask=gray_test))
```

[image: Output 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "binarize" the mask.

For your code to work properly, the mask should be a binary image.
In OpenCV, the convention of a binary image is an image with all values `0` or `255` (and type `np.uint8`).

Using only `0` and `255` is not a "must", but when using `cv2.bitwise_not(mask)`, it's important for the `mask` to be binary (then all zeros are inverted to 255, and all 255 are inverted to zeros).

The code `gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`, converts `img2` to grayscale, but not to a binary image (not all values are `0` and `255`).

You may apply thresholding for converting `gray` to binary:

```python
thres_gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # threshold (binarize) the image
```

Use `thres_gray` instead of `gray`:

```python
gray_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(thres_gray)
gray_test = cv2.bitwise_not(gray_inv)
```

---

The following code sample demonstrates the solution:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('img1.png')
img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (100,100))

img2 = cv2.imread('img2.png')
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (100,100))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thres_gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # threshold (binarize) the image

gray_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(thres_gray)
gray_test = cv2.bitwise_not(gray_inv) 

out2 = cv2.bitwise_or(img1, img1, mask=gray_inv)
out3 = cv2.bitwise_or(img1, img1, mask=gray_test)

cv2.imshow('out2', out2)
cv2.imshow('out3', out3)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

`out2`:
[image]

`out3`:
[image]

Comment: I totally agree that the mask should be a binary image and the solutions works. However in that case : 
`plt.imshow(cv2.bitwise_or(img1,img1, mask=gray_inv))` 
where gray_inv is a bitwise_not of gray image should also not work (output2). Why does the mask work there (i.e. gray_inv) ant not with the bitwise_not of gray_inv (i.e gray_test -output3) ?

Comment: The rules of OpenCV masking resembles Boolean expressions in most programming languages: `0` evaluates to `false` and other values evaluate to `true`. In your case, all values in range [1, 255] are masked as "true". The `bitwise_not` of numbers in range [0, 254] are not zeros, and are also masked as "true".

Answer (score 0):

For the effect you’re describing you don’t want a bit-wise OR. You want to multiply the values. So `output = input1 * input2 / 255`.